# Como instalar o OPENCV no PHP em um server WAMP?

Tags: php, wamp, opencv

Preciso da função de processamento de imagens OPENCV no PHP , mas estou tendo dificuldades para instalar no windows .. como proceder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem uma biblioteca PHP excelente pra isso. Requer PHP 5.3+ e OpenCV 2.0+.

Verifique se te atende: [OpenCV for PHP](https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP/tree/master)

Comment: Valeu @EduardoAlmeida mas como instalar isso no windows man ? pois no linux é mais facil (pelo terminal)

Comment: Você tem o PHP e o OpenCV no seu computador instalados?

Comment: Tenho o php, baixei o OpenCv, mas não sei instalar a biblioteca no PHP